# Make dynamically added div draggable in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-draggable

I have function which bind draggable functionality to newly added div.

Something like this:

```
function bind_draggable($el){
    $el.draggable({
        //options...
    });
}

var $container = $('#container'),
    $div = $(<some content here>);

$container.append($div);
bind_draggable($div);
```

It works fine in all browsers but fails in **IE8**. I tried to add `ready()` handler to `$div`, but this doesn't help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why draggable doesn't work in IE < 9 is `distance: 15` declaration in draggable options. In fact `delay` option is also incompatible with IE < 9

Comment: Any work around for this?  I tried adding in a time out in the start function  and it basically made it stop working.  I really need a way to ignore short/small drags that is cross browser compatible.  IE 8 is being a pita.

Comment: I couldn't find this limitation documented anywhere. Can you point me to where you saw it?